# Is it valid to set the value of changing control property equal to a constant in swift?

Tags: swift

I apologize for the rather basic question, there is a lot of documentation out there but this is not particularly clear to me.

Swift keeps giving me warnings that suggest changing variables to constants so my question is this: if I set a constant equal to a control property (a label text value for instance) and the value of that control property changes, will the value of the constant change? The definition of that "constant" will always be equal to the control property.

Example from my code:

```
let MELLandingPenalty: Int = Int(lblMELLandingDist.text!)!
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? I don't think a "dump" is needed, the question is pretty clear. It'll help with giving you the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, I'll edit the question and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants behave in two different ways:

- If the assigned object is **value type** then the value is a copy of the right side and will never change.
- If the assigned object is **reference type** then the reference will never change but its variable properties are mutable.

In your example value type `MELLandingPenalty` will **never** change – by the way variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter and don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

Trust the compiler and resolve the warnings by changing `var` to `let`.